# ruby on rails 3.1 web design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, compass-sass, blueprint-css

May I ask you how to make rails web design more efficient?

Is compass plus blueprint the perfect match?

Is the current version of compass support rails3.1

Are there any other frameworks that will make rails web deign easier?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely a framework like compass is awesome, it includes a lot of helpers, and provides a good solid base.

For form-styling I would recommend using a gem like [formtastic][1], which not only greatly simplifies making forms, but also provides a standard css file. So all needed tags are then known (and can be overwritten if needed).

There a few alternatives to kickstart your application's layout:

- [twitter-bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/): it is plainly awesome and  provides a great start (it does not play nice with formtastic, but works perfectly well with simple_form).
- [web-app-theme](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) provides generators, and a set of templates to style your application quickly
- [activo](https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme) is a template that is contained in web-app-theme, but can also be used standalone

Hope this helps.

Comment: may I ask you that what role compass plays when it comes to web design?  Can blueprint alone do the css stuff?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904072/rails-compass-advantages-vs-using-haml-blueprint-directly Compass is just a toolbox that makes some things easier. You have to decide which tools you want to use. With regards to `design`, it actually does nothing, except make some things easier. E.g. to give a box rounded corners, you now just have to `@include border-radius(25px);`, but if you rather write the css yourself, or use images, that is totally up to you. Compass is just a toolset, but you have to create the design yourself.