# RoR and web design (css)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I am starting server side programming with RoR. I am noticing that it's tightly coupled with css/html web design. (Maybe I am just perceiving it that way since this is my first time doing server side stuff).

I just want to know, are server side programmers usually well knowledgeable in css/html layout stuff? I understand the ruby part, but css is giving me a headache. Debugging with different browsers/testing/ a lot of trial and error and still buggy. Finally you get it to work with Firefox and I.E doesn't work anymore...

How do server-side programmers out there usually tackle the "looks"/UI? Do they get someone else to do the css stuff and worry mostly about the functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076443/ruby-on-rails-3-1-web-design/8076693#8076693).

Most of the times from something basic, like twitter-bootstrap is now fantastic to get something up and running quickly.

What happens next is up to you: either you have some interest and learn some design skills. Or you get in touch with a designer to do the designing for you. I seriously think you will need to have some HTML/CSS skills yourself, but that is not the same as designing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the development shop your working for I suppose.  Larger companies tend to have some people focus on the backend, and some on the front end to best suit peoples talents.

I would highly recommend becoming familiar with the front end UI as well for your own benefit though.  Most small web development shops are seeking full stack developers that can manage all aspects of the web app from server configuration, backend logic, and UI.  You'll be much more well rounded in solving your own challenges, and become a more valuable employee with a diverse skill set.

Since your using RoR I would recommend becoming familiar with SASS and Coffescript since they can save a lot of development time.  Also sass provides excellent mixin features to help solve your CSS cross browser issues, which you can find several prepackaged ones in Thoughtbots bourbon gem. https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon

Answer (score 0):

The question is impossible to answer.

*Many* server-side devs are well-versed in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, at least up to the "Oh that's the IE7 off-by-one bounding rectangle absolute-div positioning bug" point.

However, I think some *groups* of server-side devs are generally more adept than others: server-side environments like RoR, PHP, and so on tend to push more HTML/CSS onto the devs than, say, Java.

For me, the trick has been to keep the HTML and CSS relatively clean (sass/scss helps a lot), not obsess about pixel-perfect cross-browser appearances, and have layouts that you don't have to mess with much. There are HTML/CSS frameworks that help in this regard.

Conversely, a lot of designers don't know enough JavaScript to be useful--I think it *is* important for site developers to know enough JavaScript to provide the necessary functionality. Here again, the frameworks tend to breed different levels of JavaScript awareness, although that's changed somewhat as more sites get more interactive.